# How can I hit test between two arrays whilst switching between movieclips within those arrays?

Tags: actionscript

I am making a platforming game in which I must switch between colliding the character between two Arrays (whiteBlocks and blackBlocks) as well as another Array (redBlocks) that is activated on button collision and is timed.

However, I am having trouble with the hitTest code I have used to ensure that I can use redBlocks as a platform as well as either whiteBlocks or blackBlocks at the same time. I was wandering if anyone could help me to have the redBlocks constantly active once the timer has been triggered and is not effective by switching between blackBlocks or whiteBlocks.

If you would like me to explain my problem in a clearer way I will do. Please note that I am quite new to actionscript and coding in general so apologies for errors I may make. I appreciate any help you can offer as I have been troubleshooting this for a while now.

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip
import flash.display.DisplayObject;


//PLAYER MOVEMENT
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyLIST);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyLIST);

manMC.positionPNT = new Point (manMC.x, manMC.y);

//track using loop and keypresses, not just keyEvent
var leftKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var rightKeyDown:Boolean = false;

function keyLIST (ke:KeyboardEvent) {

    //trace(ke.toString() );

    //1. work out where we're going from where we are now

    //characterPNT = new Point(manMC.x, manMC.y);

        //2. offset our destination point
        switch (ke.keyCode) {

        //LEFT
        case 37:

            trace(ke.type);
            leftKeyDown = (ke.type == "keyDown");

        break;

        //RIGHT
        case 39:

            //moveCharacter(manMC, "right");
            rightKeyDown = (ke.type == "keyDown");

        break;

        //87UP, 83DOWN

        //UP
        case 38:

            trace("true");

            manMC.jump();

        break;

        //DOWN
        case 83:



        break;

        default:

            //trace ("this key does nothing");

        break;
    }// close switch

}// end function keyLIST

function movementCallback (ev:Event):void {

    if (leftKeyDown == true) {

        moveCharacter(manMC, "left");

    }

    if (rightKeyDown == true) {

        moveCharacter(manMC, "right");
    }
}

addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, movementCallback);

//a new movement function
function moveCharacter(char:character, dir:String ):void {//datatype as void as it returns nothing

    //will need this
    //var characterPNT:Point; //moved to character class
    //maMC.positionPNT = new Point( manMC.x, manMC.y);

    //copy current poistion before offsetting with movement, speed and direction
    manMC.destinationPNT = manMC.positionPNT.clone();
    //characterPNT = new Point(manMC.x, manMC.y);

    //var colliding:Boolean;

    //do multiple collision detection here

    var offsetPNT:Point;//detecting the destination of the body points

    switch (dir) {

        case "left":

            //move PNT to left
            manMC.destinationPNT.x -= manMC.speedNUM;
            offsetPNT = manMC.leftarmPNT;

        break;

        case "right":

            //move PNT to right
            manMC.destinationPNT.x += manMC.speedNUM;
            offsetPNT = manMC.rightarmPNT;



        break;
    }

    //set to true of false by the function that returns a Boolean value
    var colliding:Boolean = multipleHitTest (manMC.positionPNT, manMC.destinationPNT, offsetPNT, activeArray);

    //trace(colliding);
    //trace ("moveMode: " + manMC.moveModeSTR);

    if (!colliding /*&& manMC.moveModeSTR != "falling"*/) { //may be more complex to control player movement when falling&jumping

        manMC.moveToPoint( manMC.destinationPNT );

        //manMC.x = manMC.destinationPNT.x;
        //manMC.y = manMC.destinationPNT.y;

        //always update position PNT when character is moved
        //manMC.positionPNT = manMC.destinationPNT.clone();//copies destination point 
    }
}


//Apply gravity at all times using a loop/callback
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gravityFUNC);

var gravityNUM:Number = new Number(10);

function gravityFUNC (ev:Event) {

    var falling:Boolean;

    var gravityPNT:Point = manMC.positionPNT.clone();
    //trace(manMC.positionPNT.y);

    gravityPNT.y += gravityNUM;
    //trace(gravityPNT.y);

    //EXPERIMENTAL
    gravityPNT.y -= manMC.verticalVelocityNUM;

    //decaying gravity, caping it at 0 to avoid negatives
    manMC.verticalVelocityNUM = Math.max ( 0, manMC.verticalVelocityNUM - gravityNUM);


    falling = !multipleHitTest (manMC.positionPNT, gravityPNT, manMC.feetPNT, activeArray);
    //trace("falling " + falling);

    if (falling == true) {
        //manMC.y = gravityPNT.y;
        manMC.moveToPoint(gravityPNT);

        //either jumping or falling
        if ( manMC.verticalVelocityNUM == 0) {

            manMC.moveModeSTR = "falling";

        }else {

            manMC.moveModeSTR = "jumping";
        }

    } else {

        manMC.moveModeSTR = "walking";

    }
}

//======================================================================



//======================================================================


//add when declared
//varobstacles:Array = new Array (block0MC, block1MC, block2MC);

//declared and then new instance
//var obstacles:Array;
//obstacles = new Array (block6MC);

//declares and create empty array
/*var obstacles:Array = new Array();
//push adds an item to the front of an array
obstacles.push (block0MC); // add instance names of display objects (or other data)
obstacles.push (block1MC);
obstacles.push (block2MC);
obstacles.push (block3MC);*/


//trace("length of list" + obstacles.length);
//trace(obstacles[0]); //access first element of array

//trace( block0MC["x"] );// acessing x property using different method

function multipleHitTest( position:Point, destination:Point, offset:Point, targets:Array):Boolean { //these are ARGUMENTS

    //track hittest true or false
    var returnBOOL:Boolean = new Boolean (false);

    // cap length of loop - ie.e how many iterations?
    var limit:int = new int ( targets.length );// obstacles.length is 3 items long


    //the "counter", increases or decreases each time
    var i:int;

    //chunks =
    //start counter at 0;
    // loop while counter is less than limit;
    // increment counter by 1 each looop;

    for( i=0; i<limit; i++) {


        //will access each item in array, as "i" is an integer
        //obstacles[1];

        //because it's targeted as a movieclip we can ask it's name

        //this is 'reference variable'
        //we are creating an 'alias' of the item in the list
        var testAgainstObject:DisplayObject = targets[i];



        //track direction
        var moveDirection:String;

        //only hit test things we're moving towards...
        if (position.x < destination.x) { //if we're moving right 

            moveDirection = new String( "right" );

        } else if (position.x > destination.x) {//else if we're moving left

            moveDirection = new String( "left" );

        }

        //
        if(

           (moveDirection == "right" && targets[i].x >= position.x && destination.x >= targets[i].x)
           ||//or
           (moveDirection == "left" && targets[i].x <= position.x && destination.x <= (targets[i].x + targets[i].width) )

           ) {//obstacle is to the right

            //  obstacle moving right
            // moving right

        }

        //create a copy of 'destination' 
        var offsetDestination:Point = destination.clone();

        //apply our offset provided by our character limbs
        offsetDestination.offset(offset.x, offset.y);

        //if point is colliding with list item
        //if( testAgainstObject.hitTestPoint (destination.x, destination.y) ) { //REMOVED FOR TESTING
        if( testAgainstObject.hitTestPoint (offsetDestination.x, offsetDestination.y) ) {

            //trace("collisiondetected " + targets[i].name);
            returnBOOL = true;

        } else {
            //trace("no collision");

            //do nothing if flase, as it would contradict a 'true' value set earlier in the loop

        }

    }

    return (returnBOOL); //tesing only
}


//declares and create empty array
var blackBlocks:Array = new Array();
//push adds an item to the front of an array
blackBlocks.push (block0MC); // add instance names of display objects (or other data)
blackBlocks.push (block1MC);
blackBlocks.push (blackbarrier);
blackBlocks.push (blackbarrier2);
blackBlocks.push (blackbarrier3);
blackBlocks.push (blackbarrier4);
blackBlocks.push (blackbarrier5);



var whiteBlocks:Array = new Array();
//push adds an item to the front of an array
whiteBlocks.push (block2MC);
whiteBlocks.push (block3MC);
whiteBlocks.push (whitebarrier);
whiteBlocks.push (whitebarrier2);
whiteBlocks.push (whitebarrier3);
whiteBlocks.push (whitebarrier4);
whiteBlocks.push (whitebarrier5);

var redBlocks:Array = new Array();
redBlocks.push (redblock1MC);



//var activeArray:Array = new Array (blackBlocks);

var activeArray:Array = blackBlocks;
//active.push (redblock1MC);



//Adds an event listener to the button component with the mouse click event.
//hide_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleBlocks);
//show_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showObject);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, toggleBlocks);



// start toggle blocks
function toggleBlocks (event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    var i:int = 0;
    var lim:int = activeArray.length;

    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
    trace("Toggle Blocks");

    blocksVisibility( activeArray , false );

    if( activeArray == blackBlocks) { 
        activeArray = whiteBlocks;

    }else{ 

    activeArray = blackBlocks;



    }

    blocksVisibility( activeArray , true );

} // end IF



} // end toggle blocks

function blocksVisibility( arrARG:Array , visBOOL:Boolean ){

    var i:int = 0;
    var lim:int = arrARG.length;

    for( i=0; i<lim; i++) {
        arrARG[i].visible = visBOOL;
    }

}

blocksVisibility( this.whiteBlocks , false );
blocksVisibility( this.redBlocks , false );

//blocksVisibility( this.redBlocks , false );


//======== red block button ========


// on collision trigger button and make red platform appear

/*
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(5000,1);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);

function timerListener(e:TimerEvent):void {
    //logo_mc.x+=40;
    blocksVisibility( this.redBlocks , true );
    //redBlock1MC:Array = true;

    //activeArray:Array = redBlocks;
}

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onComplete);
function onComplete(e:TimerEvent):void {
    //logo_mc.alpha=10;
    //logo_mc.x=20;
    blocksVisibility( this.redBlocks , false );
    //redBlock1MC:Array = false;

    //activeArray:Array = blackBlocks;
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onStart);

function onStart(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode == 88){

    blocksVisibility( this.redBlocks , true );
    //redBlock1MC:Array = true;

    myTimer.start();
    //logo_mc.alpha=.1;
    //logo_mc.x=20;
}
} */





var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(10000, 1); // 1 second

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timedPlatform);
//myTimer.start();

function timedPlatform(event:TimerEvent):void {


trace("timedPlatform() called @ " + getTimer() + " ms");


blocksVisibility( this.redBlocks , false );

/*if (manMC.hitTestObject(redButton)){


trace("Start Timer");
myTimer.start();


blocksVisibility( this.redBlocks , true );

        activeArray = redBlocks;


} */
}



redButton.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startTimer);
function startTimer(event:Event):void{
//if (e.keyCode == 88){

//if (manMC, hitTest(redButton)) {

if (manMC.hitTestObject(redButton)) {


trace("Start Timer");
myTimer.start();


blocksVisibility( this.redBlocks , true );

activeArray = blackBlocks;
//activeArray = blackBlocks;



/*if( activeArray == blackBlocks) { 
        activeArray = redBlocks;
                activeArray = blackBlocks;


    }else{ 

    activeArray = blackBlocks;



    }*/





} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making activeArray a reference to whiteBlocks or blackBlocks, make it a separate Array object.  Then, in toggleBlocks, you can

1. remove all elements from activeArray
2. add all elements from redBlocks to activeArray (optional depending on the current state)
3. add all elements from whiteBlocks OR blackBlocks to activeArray

This way activeArray will have all red blocks AND (all whiteBlocks OR all blackBlocks).

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply, I will go away and give this a go, will report back soon.